# iOS view object properties vs action methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Just need some clarification on view objects. If anything I mention here isn't clear, let me know.

Just a few questions:

What does creating a property do exactly for an object such as a label?

Why don't we need to create properties for certain buttons that we create?

Why do we have to create properties for certain view objects? I ask this because I had created a switch but I wanted to use it's value to send to my model, but I had to create a property to make it work. Is this related to the switch's getter and setter?

Comment: Yeah, it is not clear. Try to rephrase your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does creating a property do exactly for an object such as a label?

When you say "creating a property", I assume you mean creating an `IBOutlet` property in the view controller to reference the label in question. The purpose is to allow you to programmatically interact with that label (e.g. change the text it displays, etc.). If you're not going to be interacting with that label (e.g. its just a prompt), then no `IBOutlet` is needed. But if you need to interact with it (e.g. change its value based upon some other user input elsewhere), then you might have an `IBOutlet`.

> Why don't we need to create properties for certain buttons that we create?

You only need to create `IBOutlet` references for those objects you'll be interacting with programmatically (e.g. changing the text on the button, retrieving the value of a switch), but otherwise you don't need an `IBOutlet` property. You might, in the case of a button, have an `IBAction`, or if using segues, you might not even need that. You often don't need `IBOutlet` property references for buttons at all (but you *can* have one if you need it for any reason).

But in short, you only need to create `IBOutlet` property references for those controls that you'll be interacting with in your own code.

---

> Why do we have to create properties for certain view objects? I ask this because I had created a switch but I wanted to use it's value to send to my model, but I had to create a property to make it work. Is this related to the switch's getter and setter?

If you want to access the status of the `UISwitch` from some random method, then, yes, the getter method will make it easy for you to do so. And by defining a property, the getter method will be synthesized for you.

On the other hand, if you have a `IBAction` associated with the "value changed" event for your `UISwitch`, you can access it from the `sender` parameter with no additional property needed.

```
- (IBAction)changedSwitchValue:(id)sender
{
    UISwitch *switchControl = sender;

    if (switchControl.on)
        NSLog(@"Switch is on");
    else
        NSLog(@"Switch is off");
}
```

But if you want to access the `on` property of the `UISwitch` from other methods, having an `IBOutlet` property reference is quite useful.

Comment: By the way, the _Cocoa Fundamentals Guide_ has a [discussion on outlets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW3), though I hesitate to present it because it focuses on instance variables (which is technically right, but the modern convention is to use properties, for which the compiler will instantiate the necessary instance variables for us, and to _not_ declare the ivars ourselves anymore). Nonetheless, the Cocoa Fundamentals Guide is a good read.

Comment: What is the purpose of making an `IBAction` that is clearly only for a switch an `(id)` instead of `(UISwitch)`?

Comment: @LéMuffinMan It's more of a historic convention than anything else (and when you look at the [Target-Action](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009071-CH3-SW1) discussion they use `id`, too). But you can declare the `sender` parameter to be a `UISwitch *` pointer directly, rather than a generic `id` pointer, if you prefer. When you create your `IBAction` in Interface Builder, while it defaults to `id`, you have the option to declare the "Type" of the action to be either `id` or `UISwitch *`.

Answer (score 1):

> What does creating a property do exactly for an object such as a label?

Properties are used to generate getters and setters  for instance variables
You can implement the same accessors by hand. in case you are talking about `IBOutlet` then it is the way to interact between GUI object  & code (where you access the properties of the object), `IBOutlet` becomes a connection between the Object added on the user interface and the code

> Why don't we need to create properties for certain buttons that we create?

Sometimes when you create an object programatticaly without using the .xib or GUI then you don't need to create the `IBOutlet` instead you could use only a property without outlet in your class to access the properties of the object, but in this case you will have to manually set all the methods as selector for the objects e.g in case of `UIButton` .

[You can find good references here to get to know how it works in practice](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/)